# Ionic4 - issue with login to Azure AD when app is run from Intune Company Portal

Tags: android, azure, cordova, ionic-framework, azure-active-directory

I have an `Ionic application 4 (cordova core)` with `authorization` to `Azure AD` implemented using `ionic-appauth (0.4.4)` and generally it works on `iOS` and `Android` when I fetch app from official market `(App Store/Google Play store)`.
But I also have `Intune Company Portal (Microsoft Azure service for managing devices)` and when I put app in this service and fetch from it:

- on `iOS` device still works properly

> - on Android device the app appears in Managed Google Play store and after correct login to Azure AD occurs issue 'ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME'
>   (correct behaviour: Intune/Chrome? should redirect back to the app).

**What might cause this issue?**

[Screenshot with issue on Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nz70a.jpg)

This issue is described here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=181186

Comment: I fixed this issue by installing Chrome through Intune Company Portal - then callback from Azure AD works fine.